# How is ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor and ScheduledFuture differ between java app and android app

Tags: java, android

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

ScheduledFuture now = null;
Button roll, continuous, exit, stop;
TextView two, three, four13,four22, five14,five32, six51,six42,six33, seven61,



    public class RollDice extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

ScheduledFuture now = null;


private static final int WIDTH = 450;
 private static final int HEIGHT = 1100;
priva
```

How is this different all together its the same program, it works in the java application but it doesnt work in the android app, but i get no errors